# How to iterate to have a modal content modulable with an array datas ? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

```
const arrayDatasModal = [
    [ "Modélisation d'un challet", "Modélisation d'une chambre", "Modélisation d'un appartement", "Modélisation en 3D d'un aménagement extérieur", "Modélisation d'une maison","Modélisation d'un appartemment","Modélisation d'unne chambre", "Modélisation en 3D d'un appartemment"],
    ["img/portfolio/Chalet-Allos-scaled.jpeg","img/portfolio/master-room-scaled.jpeg","img/portfolio/renovation-appartement-3D-à-cannes-1.jpeg","img/portfolio/Modélisation en 3D d'un aménagement extérieur.jpg","img/portfolio/ENTRE INSTA.jpg","img/portfolio/renovation-appartement-3D-à-cannes-2.jpeg","img/portfolio/rénovation-chambre-en-3D-à-Nice.jpeg","img/portfolio/renovation-appartement-3D-à-cannes-1.jpeg"],
];
const modalOpener = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-launcher')

const wrapper = document.querySelector(".modal-wrapper"),
header = wrapper.querySelector("header");

function createContentModal(){
    wrapper.style.visibility = 'visible';

    const modalName = document.querySelector('.modal-title h3');
    modalName.textContent = arrayDatasModal[0][0];

    const modalImg = document.querySelector('.modal-img');
    modalImg.src = arrayDatasModal[1][0];
};

for (let i = 0; i < modalOpener.length; i++) {
    modalOpener[i].addEventListener("click", createContentModal);
}
```

Hello ! I have a little issue with this code...
I'm able to launch a modal when clicking on all the ('.modal-launcher') elements, but i would like to be able to iterate on my first array to have my modal content altered with the array datas, without the need to create the modals one by one, and I'm having trouble finding a solution. A charitable soul could help me ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest approach would be to pass index as argument to `createContentModal`

```js
function createContentModal(index) {
    wrapper.style.visibility = "visible";

    const modalName = document.querySelector(".modal-title h3");
    modalName.textContent = arrayDatasModal[0][index];

    const modalImg = document.querySelector(".modal-img");
    modalImg.src = arrayDatasModal[1][index];
}

for (let i = 0; i < modalOpener.length; i++) {
    modalOpener[i].addEventListener("click", () => createContentModal(i));
}
```